# Is there a button in Audience (Videos Application) to switch to full screen?

Tags: audience, video-player

When I click the maximize button in the top right corner in Audience (the Videos Application) the header as well as the line with date and time and the indicators are still there. This seems kind of annoying when watching a longer video.

For now, I solved the problem by defining a full screen shortcut for any window in the system settings but I was wondering whether there is a more smooth solution like a button?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just double click inside the video frame.

Comment: ... and like everything else poorly documented.